# ADLS Client Bulk Download - downloading files but no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-data-lake

I want to download a directory from Azure Data Lake Store to my local directory and I am using this method- [Bulk Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkdownload?view=azure-dotnet). The issue is that when I run my code its downloading the files as expected but the files have no data and their sizes also show 0KBs.

Here is how I am using the method-

```
string srcPath = "/souce path included/"; 
string dstPath = "C:/Users/keprasad/Documents/Views/"; 
clientProd.BulkDownload(srcPath, dstPath);
```

I am fairly confident that I have created the client correctly with right credentials as it is not throwing an error and actually downloading the files. Anyone has an idea as to when this scenario can occur and what needs to be done to remedy it?

PS: Actually my very first question in Stackoverflow(excited for the future!)

Comment: Could you please check TransferStatus to get more details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkdownload?view=azure-dotnet?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I checked it out and I was getting forbidden error while trying to open the files so it downloaded the files but could not open it.

Comment: Could you please tell mw how you do auth?

Comment: I am using a client ID and a secret for authentication. I am not using any authorization methods, but I think my client ID might not have the correct permissions to read these files. TransferStatus helped me in knowing this, I will look into giving the appropriate permissions to this client. Thanks a lot @JimXu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a service principal to access Azure data lake gen1, we need to configure the right Access control for the sp. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory).

For example. I want to download file (/Seattle/Portland/Data.txt). we need to configure ACL for the sp as below.

[image]

Code

download a single file

```
 string appId = "";
            string appSecret = "";
            string domain = "";

            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = new Uri(@"https://datalake.azure.net/");
            
            var creds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, appId, appSecret, serviceSettings);

            string accountName = "";
            AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient($"{accountName}.azuredatalakestore.net", creds);
            string fileName = "/Seattle/Portland/data.txt";
            string line = null;
            using (var readStream = new StreamReader(client.GetReadStream(fileName)))
            {
                while ((line =  await readStream.ReadLineAsync()) != null) {

                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
               
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

2. Bulk download

```
string appId = "";
            string appSecret = "";
            string domain = "";

            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = new Uri(@"https://datalake.azure.net/");

            var creds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, appId, appSecret, serviceSettings);

            string accountName = "";
            AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient($"{accountName}.azuredatalakestore.net", creds);
            string srcPath = "/Seattle/Portland/";
            string desPath = @"D:\sample";
            TransferStatus status =client.BulkDownload(srcPath, desPath);
```

[image]